# React router v4 - Browser router not rendering parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Currently I'm trying to make it so that my parent router is activated each time. I'm not very sure of the terminology here.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/browserRouterPath' component={loginComponent}/>
    <HashRouter>
      <Route path='/hashRouterPath' component={loginComponent2}/> 
      <Route path='/' component={loggedInComponent}/>
    </HashRouter>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

LoggedInComponent

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path='/' render={() => (
                             <Redirect to: {{pathname: '/finalComponent'> }}/> 
                             )}> />
...
</Switch>
```

My current problem is that my components in the hashRouter are not being called.
When the loggedInComponent redirects it to the new path, the hashRouter is not called.

However, if I remove the hashRouter in the first block of code. The hashRouter is called without incident, but that breaks the CSS/styling of the components in the program.

Is there a way to render the parent component each time? Or is there a workaround that eliminates the hashRouter but keeps the CSS for me?

Comment: What is the parent component here? Also, how is hashRouter "called" after you've removed it? The whole question is really unclear to me.

Comment: @ChrisG The parent component here is loggedInComponent. When the loggedInComponent is redirected to /finalComponent, the hashRouter is not called anymore. What I meant by "removing hashRouter" is that I'm talking about an alternative fix. It can fix it but it's not what I want

Comment: But how is loggedInComponent a parent? It's inside a Switch and inside a HashRouter and has no children.

Comment: "I'm not familiar with the terminology." What should I call it then? The nested component?

Comment: Well, is it supposed to contain other components? And do you have a state variable that stores whether the user is logged in? As for the terminology, in your JSX, <HashRouter> for instance is the parent component of two <Route> children.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to contain other components. Yes there is a state variable that stores if the user is logged in. The logging in is already taken care of but the loggedInComponent still needs to be called.

Comment: Ok, then you basically need `{userIsLoggedIn && <LoggedInComponent><Switch>...</Switch></LoggedInComponent>}` (the URL doesn't determine the logged in state; you need to deal with logged in state and URLs separately)